# Subsetting the lowest 5% of the observations of a vector

Tags: r

I have a data.frame and want to select the rows that contain the lowest 5% values in one of the columns.

Is there an easy way, instead of having to sort the data, count the num of observations and then select the first 5% rows?

Thanks,

Juan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find the smallest 5% value using the `quantile` function, then filter your data frame for smaller than that value:

```
df[df$value <= quantile(df$value, .05),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `quantile` does exactly this.

```
x <- runif(100)
five.pc <- quantile(x, probs = 0.05)

x[x < five.pc]
```